# Using quarto and ConTeXt to generate PDF

Tags: context, lualatex-dev

I'm new to ConTeXt, I know some LaTeX as I have used it to produce some documents in the past.

I'm using [quarto](https://quarto.org/) to produce some documents and I want to fine tune the PDF by editing `.tex` output, and then compiling with ConTeXt.

In quarto, I have set the `context: context` option and `pdf-engine:lualatex` in header, as it seems `luametatex` engine is not a valid option yet.

Quarto generates a `.tex` file correctly using `lualatex` engine, but not PDF. Then I can't compile that file with `context`. I get this error (showing first lines in .tex output from `context` compiling:

.tex first lines:

```
% Options for packages loaded elsewhere
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names}{xcolor}
```

ConTeXt compilation error:

```
open source     > level 1, order 2, name './prueba_quarto_ConTeXt.tex'
tex error       > tex error on line 2 in file ./prueba_quarto_ConTeXt.tex: Undefined control sequence \undefined

<line 3.2>
    \PassOptionsToPackage
    {Unicode}{hyperref}
```

Is quarto generating LaTeX output and not ConTeXt?

Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't think context uses packages and usually not that syntax, so I'd say that that is LaTeX output.

Comment: `pdf-engine:lualatex` looks definitively wrong as you want to use context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved: it was a misunderstanding on my part of quarto header configuration to generate context output. The good one is simply:

```
---
title: "Testing Quarto with ConTeXt"
format: context
pdf-engine: context
editor: visual
----
```

Works like a charm.

Thanks for help!